# Cannot find name 'signal' in Angular 17.2

Tags: angular, signals

I cant use the signals in Angular 17.2. I get : Cannot find name 'signal'.

```
import { signal } from './signals'
...
ng version (says: 17.2)
...
i = signal(0); (says: Cannot find name 'signal')
```

Why I cant use signals in Angular 17.2 ?

Comment: We're going to need more info here. Do you import signal ?

Comment: I copy pasted from an from and stackblitz example : import { signal } from './signals';  but the result the same (my VSCode is not fine tuned for Angular at the moment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`signal` should be imported from `@angular/core`

Comment: you are right, I dont understand why I run into Stackblitz examples with this import :  import { signal } from './signals'; Thank you